# Adding component with inner placeholder breaks placeholder settings

Tags: jss, placeholders

I have component

```
manifest.addComponent({
  name: 'MyComponentWithPlaceholder',
  icon: SitecoreIcon.DocumentTag,
  fields: [
    { name: 'heading', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
  ],
  placeholders: ['my-placeholder']
});
```

with implementation

```
const MyComponentWithPlaceholder = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>My component with <strong>Placeholder</strong></p>
    <Text field={props.fields.heading} />
    <Placeholder name='my-placeholder' rendering={props.rendering} />
  </div>
);
```

and `my-placeholder` field **Allowed Controls** filled with some components...

[image: Field Allowed Controls in my-placeholder item]

**But**, when I'm trying to add this component to layout in experience editor, inner placeholder `my-placeholder` is behaving like it did not contain any *allowed controls*.

[image: Empty dialog]

*However, after saving state of layout (in experience editor), `my-placeholder` let me correctly select component, that I'm allowed to add to parent component.*

What I'm doing wrong? I don't want to save layout state after every added component.

Comment: I have the same, and use the save workaround.

Comment: According Sitecore Support there is another workaround that can sometimes fit your needs. You can add a next placeholder settings with **undefined** key where you can set the allowed components. Of course, this will apply for all inner placeholders then in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is a known issue (documented in the [Help Page of JSS Docs](https://jss.sitecore.com/help#other-known-issues)), and unfortunately it causes a lot of confusion for those encountering it for the first time.

Saving the page to resolve the issue is the current recommended workaround.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I marked your answer as an accepted one, although the proposed workaround is far from an ideal solution. Instructs content editors to save the page if a Renderings dialog is empty feels wrong...

Comment: Totally agreed. We have this in our backlog.